# Cannot build HID USB client using Windows Human Interface Devices (HID) API

Tags: c++, windows, hid

I need to communicate with HID USB devices on windows. Unfortunately I cannot use libusb and therefore decided to use Windows Human Interface Devices (HID) API.
I cannot build my test application - linker cannot find corresponding symbols and it is strange(I have this lib on my computer).

Here is Makefile

```
    CXX := g++
    CXXFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11
    LIBS := -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22000.0/um/x64" -lhid
    SOURCES := main.cpp 
    OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
    EXECUTABLE := myprogram
    $(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
    
    %.o: %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    
    clean:
        rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

and my test program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <hidsdi.h>
#include <hidpi.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE device_handle = nullptr;
    PHIDP_PREPARSED_DATA preparsed_data = nullptr;
// Commented compiler error to resolve linker error first...
//    device_handle = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\HID_DEVICE_NAME", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, nullptr);
    if (device_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        if (HidD_GetPreparsedData(device_handle, &preparsed_data)) {
            HIDP_CAPS capabilities;
            if (HidP_GetCaps(preparsed_data, &capabilities) == HIDP_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                USHORT value_caps_length = capabilities.NumberInputValueCaps;
                PHIDP_VALUE_CAPS value_caps = new HIDP_VALUE_CAPS[value_caps_length];

                if (HidP_GetValueCaps(HidP_Input, value_caps, &value_caps_length, preparsed_data) == HIDP_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                    for (USHORT i = 0; i < value_caps_length; ++i) {
                        std::cout << "Value Capabilities " << i << ":" << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "Usage Page: " << value_caps[i].UsagePage << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "Report ID: " << value_caps[i].ReportID << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "Bit Field: " << value_caps[i].BitField << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "Logical Minimum: " << value_caps[i].LogicalMin << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "Logical Maximum: " << value_caps[i].LogicalMax << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "Physical Minimum: " << value_caps[i].PhysicalMin << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "Physical Maximum: " << value_caps[i].PhysicalMax << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "Units: " << value_caps[i].Units << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "Units Exp: " << value_caps[i].UnitsExp << std::endl;
                        std::cout << "Is Absolute: " << (value_caps[i].IsAbsolute ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
                    }
                }

                delete[] value_caps;
            }

            HidD_FreePreparsedData(preparsed_data);
        }

        CloseHandle(device_handle);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and results of the build:

```
C:\Users\piffo\go\src\tassta.com\work_with_usb\3>make g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11  -o myprogram main.o -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22000.0/um/x64" -lhid  
    
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `HidD_GetPreparsedData(void*, _HIDP_PREPARSED_DATA**)'

C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `HidP_GetCaps(_HIDP_PREPARSED_DATA*, _HIDP_CAPS*)'

C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `HidP_GetValueCaps(_HIDP_REPORT_TYPE, _HIDP_VALUE_CAPS*, unsigned short*, _HIDP_PREPARSED_DATA*)'
    
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4c3): undefined reference to `HidD_FreePreparsedData(_HIDP_PREPARSED_DATA*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:8: myprogram] Error 1
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `gcc` on Windows instead of `lc`?

Comment: Nowhere in your makefile are you telling `gcc` where the Windows header files are located...